# How to use cepstral swift for tts instead jovie in kde L?

Tags: kde, accessibility

So I'm running KDE settings, in kttsmgr.

I go add Talker, and try to add a swift talker:

```
/opt/swift/bin/swift -p "speech/rate=180" %t -o %w
```

..per the [instructions here](http://www.cepstral.com/support/faq/developer/i386_solaris.html#kde), which I suspect are out of date.

But when I go OK, it says invalid talker and wipes the settings.

How can I make Text to speech in KDE use the cepstral speech engine ?

Comment: Does that command work from the command line (if you replace `%t` with the text and omit `-o %w`)

Comment: yes, but of course you have to change the %w to a file name to write to like tmp.wav .. and %t to the text you want to speak out loud. I thought it might be the "speech marks" but removing that part didn't help. I think that the latest kde needs some api backends rather than just allowing shell commands.